# Print the 3rd number and all the elements divisible by 2

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, tapply

```
nums <- 1:20
result <- nums[fill the function]
result
```

Please anyone can tell me what function to use

Comment: can you show the expected

Comment: Do you need `nums[!nums %% 2][3]#
[1] 6` or `nums[!nums %% 2]`

Comment: This isn't homework? Right?

Comment: @akrun, not quite. Supriya, this is not something for any of the `*apply` functions, this is just a vector operation. If you do `nums %% 2`, you will see the modulus operator, which returns the remainder when divided by 2. You'll notice that all those divisible by 2 are the same value (check it yourself). From there, know that `nums[...]` will work if `...` is a logical vector (true/false) or indices (integers), I think if you figure out which of `nums %% 2` are the value you need, you can wrap it with `nums[` and `]`.

Comment: I want the output as 2,3,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20

Comment: @JohnGarland No. I was giving an online coding test for some employer. There was this question. I am not able to get the both conditions at a time like printing 2,3,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do :

```
sort(c(nums[nums %% 2 == 0], nums[3]))
#[1]  2  3  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20
```

`nums %% 2 == 0` is used to subset numbers which are divisible by 2 and we add `nums[3]` to get the 3rd number. We print the final output after sorting.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But the format in test was num[........]. we should write the function inside of nums within [].

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
sort(c(nums[!nums %% 2][3], nums[!nums %% 2]))
```